# Reference an object with two attributes

Tags: java, object, attributes

I currently have a small program to complete a sales transaction.  I have the following objects (store, store_list, sale_item, sale_itemSet, inventory, & inventory_list).  **I need to get the correct *price* for the product at the specified *storeID***

```
Inventory attributes
private String prodName; 
private long prodNo; 
private float prodPrice;
private int storeID; 
private int quantity; 
private int prodReorderLvl;
```

The main program looks like this

```
//new transaction
    case 1:
      System.out.println("Enter Store Number: ");
      storeID = in.nextInt();

      //automatically generate sale number
      saleNo = saleS.getNumSales() + 1;

      //reset sale line items before staring loop
      si = new saleItem();
      si.setSaleLine(0); 

      //reset saleAmt to 0
      saleAmt = 0;

      while(yesNo != ('N'|'n'))
      {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Product Number: ");
        prodNo = in.nextLong();
        System.out.println("Product Quantity: ");
        qty = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("------------------------");
        System.out.println("Enter Another Item (Y/N): ");
        System.out.println("------------------------");
        yesNo = in.next().charAt(0);

        //generate sale line item number
        int line = si.getSaleLine() + 1;

        //get product name from
        name = prodL.getProdName((int)prodNo - 1);



        ***//get product price from inventory_list
        THIS IS THE PART I DON'T KNOW HOW TO GET***




        //create sale item object
        si = new saleItem();
        si.setSaleNo(saleNo);
        si.setSaleLine(line);
        si.setProdNo(prodNo);
        si.setProdName(name);
        si.setQuantity(qty);
        si.setProdPrice(price);

        //insert sale_item set
        saleIS.insert(si);
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I had a method in my inventory list :                            public float getProdPrice(int index)
  {
    inventory inv = array[index];
    return inv.getProdPrice();
  } ...but I keep getting incorrect price information.

Comment: Essentially: price = invL.getProdPrice(storeID);